# How to have Nodejs use k8 DNS naming in CORS

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

```js
var corsOptions = {
  origin: process.env.CLIENT_HOST,
  credentials: true
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Where `process.env.CLIENT_HOST` is `development-client-service.default`
Which looks like this

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: client
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

However the error I get from node is.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/customers. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘development-client-service.default’).
```

Where it looks like its not converting the dns to the actual address. Is there something tricky with node here?

Working locally on docker for desktop and the client cors should be http://localhost. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the kube-dns on the local system.

Comment: You can use nginx-ingress for painless CORS configuration https://imti.co/kubernetes-ingress-nginx-cors/

Comment: @AymanArif  What if I already have a back end service in front of the nodejs app that is set for port 8080?